# Get number of pages of a document

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have just implemented a Java code in order to get number of pages of a document, but it only serves for PDF files. I need to count number of pages of others files (Docx, HTML, etc). Any idea?

My code is:

```
public int numberOfPages(@RequestBody() MultipartFile inputFile) throws Exception {

    int numberOfPages = 0;
    InputStream fileName = inputFile.getInputStream();
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(fileName);

    if (document != null) {
        numberOfPages = document.getNumberOfPages();
    }

    return numberOfPages;
}
```

Comment: There is no "page number" concept in HTML. And if you want to count pages in some docx, then use an appropriate API (if it exists).

Comment: yes, this is the question, which is this Api

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499907/get-the-number-of-pages-in-a-word-document-using-aspose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get the number of pages in a word document using aspose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499907/get-the-number-of-pages-in-a-word-document-using-aspose)

Answer (score 0):

I think that that is not as easy task as it seems because the page number deppends on the size of the paper, type of the printer, size of the image, etc.

One possible solution can be to convert the input document to PDF and then you can count pages easily. You can store the PDF content as well with the original documents or you can use the toPdf(FileInputStream document) method on the fly each time when you need the page number info. It deppends on the quantity of files and performance requirements.

It can convert html, office documents, pure text and images to PDF.
You can use [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) to check the type of the uploaded file and then based on this info you can execute the proper method to convert uploaded content to PDF.

**Check the file type:**

```
public static MediaType getMediaType(final byte[] content) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content)) {
        TikaConfig tika = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        return tika.getDetector().detect(stream, metadata);
    }
}
```

**Then:**

```
MediaType mediaType = ContentTypeDetector.getMediaType(content);
String uploadedContent = mediaType.toString();

if (uploadedContent.equals("image/jpeg") {
    PDF pdf = SomeClass.jpgToPdf(...)
} else if (uploadedContent.equals(...) {
    PDF pdf = SomeClass....(...)
}
```

[iText](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-1) is a nice Java library to create PDF files from the uploaded files based on your settings.

Comment: However, if you convert PDF to Docx, maybe the result has not the same number of pages

Comment: That is possible. But why would you like to convert pdf to doc?